# How to do a default sort on cgridview in yii1

Tags: yii, cgridview, yii1.x

i have the following cgrid view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'complaint-job-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search($complaint),
    //~ 'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>$columns,
    'enableSorting'=>true,



));
```

my model code is

```
public function search($complaint)
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with    =    array('complaint_job','user');

        $criteria->compare('complaint_job.job_desc',$this->job_search, true);
        if($this->user_search)
            $criteria->addSearchCondition('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name)', $this->user_search);
        $criteria->compare('complaint_id',$complaint);
        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('job_id',$this->job_id);
        $criteria->compare('local_description',$this->local_description,true);
        $criteria->compare('employee_id',$this->employee_id);
        $criteria->order = 't.id ASC';
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

so what i basically want is to show values in the cgridview in descending order of id(primary key). is it possible?

i tried like this with no success

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
    'defaultOrder'=>'id ASC',
),
```

Comment: `'defaultOrder'=>'id DESC',` ??

Comment: @Criesto no it didnt work. is there any way to do this default sort in view file rather than in model?

Comment: are you getting any error? It is not a good idea to do this in the view you should follow the MVC structure, and why do you have `[/size]`  in the `gridview` widget ?

Comment: no i don't have it :-) yes i am getting an error 'CDbException". is there any way to do it in view?

Comment: If you want to do this in view then you'll have to customize the entire thing which I'll recommend not do. Update your question with the error that you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing sort in CDbCriteria;
That's why sorting in CGridView which uses CActiveDataProvider not work.
Remove from your model:

```
$criteria->order = 't.id ASC';
```

And add to CActiveDataProvider

```
'defaultOrder'=>'t.id ASC',
```

Comment: i will give it a try and get back to you soon

Comment: 'defaultOrder'=>'t.id ASC',

Comment: Brilliant and simple~